# remove duplicate array from array list using filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

I use this code

```
labels.map((label, key) => {
  const xAxis = (parseInt(label, 10)).toFixed(0);
  const yAxis = parseInt(this.props.dataSet.datasets[0].data[key], 10);
  const arrayAxis = [xAxis, yAxis];
  data.push(arrayAxis);
  return arrayAxis;
});
```

then i get the data list

```
["1", 1] 
["2", 1]  // duplicate
["2", 1]  // duplicate
["3", 1] 
["4", 1] 
["4", 1] 
["5", 4] 
["6", 4] 
["7", 4]
["8", 4]
["9", 4]
.....
....
...
```

How I can remove duplicate array from the array list using filter?

Comment: what is a duplicate? please add the raw data of `label`.

Comment: @NinaScholz U can see in data list

Comment: are the data ordered?

Comment: ya data is ordeerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this with a temporary object for indicating duplicates. It works for non sorted arrays as well.

```
levels.forEach((temp => (label, key) => {
    var xAxis = (parseInt(label, 10)).toFixed(0),
        yAxis = parseInt(this.props.dataSet.datasets[0].data[key], 10),
        arrayAxis =[ xAxis, yAxis];
    if (!temp[arrayAxis]) {
        temp[arrayAxis] = true;
        data.push(arrayAxis);
    }
})(Object.create(null)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with filter, but it would be much simpler using `lodash`'s `uniqBy` and `isEqual` functions.

```
_.uniqWith(arr, _.isEqual);
```

You can read about it here: https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Notice that it does involve adding a dependecy on `lodash`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var data = [["1", 1],
["2", 1],
["3", 1],
["4", 1],
["5", 4],
["6", 4],
["7", 4],
["8", 4],
["9", 4]];

const xAxis = "2";
const yAxis = 1;

const arrayAxis = [xAxis, yAxis];
if($.inArray(arrayAxis[xAxis], data) !== -1)
{
    data.push(arrayAxis);
}
console.log(data);
```

This code prevents your duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I always like to provide a generic answer rather than a tailored one to the specific question.

To me this question is about filtering the array or object items of an array according to not a simple property but a similar array or object. I would use two utility methods those i had used at some other cases previously. `Object.prototype.compare()` and `Array.prototype.compare()`. Lets see.

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
Array.prototype.compare = function(a){
  return this.every((e,i) => typeof a[i] === "object" ? a[i].compare(e) : a[i] === e);
};

var data = [["1", 1],["2", 1],["2", 1],["3", 1],["4", 1],["4", 1],["5", 4],["6", 4],["7", 4],["8", 4], ["9", 4]],
filtered = data.filter(function(e) { var f = this.find(f => f.compare(e));
                                     return !f ? this.push(e) : void 0;
                                   },[]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let res = [...new Set([1,3,45, 1, 3])]
```

output is = [1,3,45]